# Ink cannot derive SpreadLayout and SpreadAllocate for simple struct and enum

Tags: ink, smart-contract, scale-codec, substrate-contracts-node

When developing Ink! smart contracts I found that `SpreadLayout` and `SpreadAllocate` cannot be derived for simple structs or enums that are members variables of the contract and I have to implement the traits manually.

The compilation error occurs only when building the contract ( `cargo +nightly contract build`) but not when running test (`cargo +nightly test`)

for instance for the simple struct:

```
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug, scale_info::TypeInfo, StorageLayout, SpreadAllocate))]
pub struct Data {
    pub a: u64,
    pub b: u64,
}
```

fails with:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Data: SpreadAllocate` is not satisfied
  --> /../lib.rs:23:14
   |
23 |     #[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `SpreadAllocate` is not implemented for `Data`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `SpreadAllocate`:
             ()
             (A, B)
             (A, B, C)
             (A, B, C, D)
             (A, B, C, D, E)
             (A, B, C, D, E, F)
             (A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
             (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H)
           and 47 others
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `SpreadAllocate` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

adding `SpreadLayout` and `SpreadAllocate` to the derive macro fails.
Same for the enum

```
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Encode, Decode, scale_info::TypeInfo, StorageLayout, SpreadLayout))]
pub enum Type {
    Unknown,
    A,
    B,
}
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SpreadAllocate` can't be derived for the enums([issue](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1042)), so you should implement it manually.

You are deriving `SpreadLayout` wrong=) `#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(...)]` means - derive it only if the `std` feature is enabled.

But the contract build has two phases:

1. Build the contract's WASM in `no_std` mode.
2. Build fo the contract's metadata in `std` mode.

`SpreadLayout` and `SpreadAllocate` should be derived for both phases. `StorageLayout` only for `std` because it is required to generate metadata.

The right deriving:

```rust
#[derive(SpreadLayout, SpreadAllocate)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug, scale_info::TypeInfo, StorageLayout))]
pub struct Data {
    pub a: u64,
    pub b: u64,
}

#[derive(SpreadLayout)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Encode, Decode, scale_info::TypeInfo, StorageLayout))]
pub enum Type {
    Unknown,
    A,
    B,
}

impl SpreadAllocate for Type {
...
}
```

Comment: wow this works like a charm! do you have any reference or link where this is explained as you did?

Comment: No=) Soon all those traits should be removed in https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1217. After OpenBrush or ink! will describe a new storage in details and examples.

Comment: For people who are interested in knowing what could go inside `impl SpreadAllocate for Type`, here is an example:

```
    impl SpreadAllocate for Type {
        fn allocate_spread(_: &mut KeyPtr) -> Self {
            Type::Unknown
        }
    }
```