# Ink contract deployment out of gas

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node

When deploying a smart contract on local-net, polkadot.js fails with:

```
system.ExtrinsicFailed, contracts.OutOfGas
```

This seems to be due to having the following `enum` in the contract storage:

```
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug, scale_info::TypeInfo, StorageLayout))]
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Encode, Decode)]
pub enum Type {
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2,
}
```

Contract struct:

```
    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
    pub struct Contract {
        [...]
        account: ink_env::AccountId,
        size: Balance,
        deposits: Mapping<ink_env::AccountId, Balance>,
        data: Data,
        type: Type,  <----
        [...]
    }
```

Increasing max_gas_allowed to the max value does not help.
Removing `type: Type` from the contract struct leads to successful deployment.

Is this an issue with how I encoded the enum (I had to implement `SpreadAllocate` and `SpreadLayout` myself as the derive macro does not work, see [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2613/ink-cannot-derive-spreadlayout-and-spreadallocate-for-simple-struct-and-enum)) or to limitation in max_gas_allowed in local setup?

Comment: This is fixed by following the answer [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2613/ink-cannot-derive-spreadlayout-and-spreadallocate-for-simple-struct-and-enum)

Answer (score 1):

I'm reposting the comment by user mastro, so that this question no longer shows up as one without answer.

> This is fixed by following the answer [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2613/ink-cannot-derive-spreadlayout-and-spreadallocate-for-simple-struct-and-enum)