# the trait `ink_storage::traits::PackedAllocate` is not implemented

Tags: ink

As I tried to implement `PackedAllocate` `it warns cannot find derive macro PackedAllocate in this scope`. How to solve this
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2613/ink-cannot-derive-spreadlayout-and-spreadallocate-for-simple-struct-and-enum

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to implement `PackedAllocate` manually for your `Proposal` struct. An example from [the ink! docs](https://use.ink/ink-vs-solidity/#nested-mappings--custom--advanced-structures) how to do this:

```rust
    impl ink_storage::traits::PackedAllocate for Proposal {
        fn allocate_packed(&mut self, at: &Key){
            PackedAllocate::allocate_packed(&mut *self, at)
        }
    }
```